# Strange bootstrap-ui control height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have an html with only bootstrap.css linked, no js. All inputs of type text become too little in height, and letters such as p, q, y are truncated from bottom. Also, Firefox says that css rules have "height:20px" but computed value is "height:10px". Opera says computed value is 20px, but displays those controls the same way -- too narrow. Needless to say, this css works fine on angularjs.org. How can I fix this, preferrably without changing bootstrap.css file?

Html goes here

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz">
</body>
```

I noticed that inputs on the above mentioned site have "ng-pristline" css class, but that class doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Believe you're hitting the same issue I was check your line-height... I'm not sure of the best practice solution to this but I just patched it in my own css file.

Comment: Well, adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` somehow solved the problem. That was the last thing I supposed would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` somehow solved the problem. That was the last thing I supposed would help.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you're hitting the same issue I was check your line-height... I'm not sure of the best practice solution to this but I just patched it in my own css file.

master.css

```
body
{
    line-height:1em;
    //other stuff here...
}
```